# SplFileInfo::getRelativePath() ... Relative to what?

Tags: symfony-3.3

This is regarding Finder component in Symfony 3.3: The documentation of [`getRelativePath`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.3/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/SplFileInfo.php#method_getRelativePath) says: "Returns the relative path".

**Does anybody know relative to what?**

- Relative to current folder?
- Relative to app's root?
- Relative to whatever I provided as parameter to `in()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that "relative" does indeed mean "Relative to the path provided to `in()`".

An example:

```
projects
| a_sub_dir
| | foo.txt
| bar.txt
```

If, in the above setup, we execute the following code:

```
$finder = (new Finder())
    ->files()
    ->in('/projects');

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    var_dump([
        'path' => $file->getRelativePath(),
        'pathName' => $file->getRelativePathname(),
    ]);
}
```

We will receive the following output

```
array(2) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(9) "a_sub_dir"
  ["pathName"]=>
  string(17) "a_sub_dir/foo.txt"
}
array(2) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pathName"]=>
  string(7) "bar.txt"
}
```

Addendum:
When using multiple values for `in()`, and a file would be found in both values, it will be present in the loop twice. Once with relative path / pathname for each `in()` value.